# Return all hash key/value pairs with maximum value

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash (in Perl) where the values are all numbers. I need to create another hash that contains all key/value pairs from the first hash where the value is the maximum of all values.

For example, given

```
my %hash = (
    key1 => 2,
    key2 => 6,
    key3 => 6,
);
```

I would like to create a new hash containing:

```
%hash_max = (
    key2 => 6,
    key3 => 6,
);
```

I'm sure there are many ways to do this, but am looking for an elegant solution (and an opportunity to learn!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use List::Util 'max';
my $max = max(values %hash);
my %hash_max = map { $hash{$_}==$max ? ($_, $max) : () } keys %hash;
```

Or a one-pass approach (similar to but slightly different from another answer):

```
my $max;
my %hash_max;
keys %hash; # reset iterator
while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash) {
    if ( !defined $max || $value > $max ) {
        %hash_max = ();
        $max = $value;
    }
    $hash_max{$key} = $value if $max == $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This makes one pass over the data, but wastes a lot of hash writes:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
    key1 => 2,
    key2 => 6,
    key3 => 6,
);

my %hash_max = ();
my $max;
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
        if (!defined($max) || $max < $hash{$key} ) {
                %hash_max = ();
                $max = $hash{$key};
                $hash_max{$key} = $hash{$key};
        }
        elsif ($max == $hash{$key}) {
                $hash_max{$key} = $hash{$key};
        }
}

foreach my $key (keys %hash_max) {
        print "$key\t$hash_max{$key}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# sort numerically descending
my @topkey = sort {$hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a}} keys %hash;
```

Then copy the top values to %hash_max, with a loop terminator after the last max value:

```
for $key (@topkey) {
    if ($hash{$key} == $hash{$topkey[0]}) {
        $hash_max{$key} = $hash{$key}
    } else { last }
}
```

ETA: Note to the unbelievers that `last` works because the keys in `@topkey` are sorted, so we can break the loop when the value is no longer like the first one. I.e. all the following values are lower.

Comment: I really don't think you want that 'last' in there.

Comment: @davorg Why do you think that?